# How to load a Razor page from code in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am new to Asp.net and Razor pages. Is there a way to load a Razor page from code in C#? I can't seem to find a way of doing that.

```
if(resultsName.Count == 0)
{
     CreateUser(username, userEmail);
                
     // load page
}
```

Comment: I've read some tutorials and documentation, but I didn't find any help regarding this issue

Comment: So let us understand, you have an asp.net application and you want to navigate to a page that contains razor syntax? Can you add more context to the code above?

Comment: Of course, sorry for the confusion. The goal here is to load different pages depending on the user's role. So the admin gets a different page than a normal user. Therefore I am checking for the role of the logged in user and want to load the correct page but I don't know how to open the page for the user from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html.Partial or Html.RenderPartial to embed a partial view into your page. A partial is not a page(doesn't have @page directive) but I guess it might be what you are looking for.

```c#
if(resultsName.Count == 0)
{
     CreateUser(username, userEmail);
                
     Html.RenderPartial("AdminInfo");
}
```